# Reading multiple lines of input from user using Buffer Reader

Tags: java, xml

How can I take two lines of input using buffer reader and those input data should shown in XML element? Where input of each line was separated by "`:`"

Example:

```
id:streetname:city:state:zipcode:country
121:xxxx:slm:tn:636007:ind
123:yyyy:chn:tn:600009:ind
```

I can read the single line of input by using

```
String line = buf.readLine();
String[] columns = line.split(":");
```

and those data are get populated successfully in XML. 
I need help with two lines of input getting populated in XML.

```java
    public static void main(String args[]) throws IOException{
        DocumentBuilderFactory docFactory =  DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
        docFactory.setNamespaceAware(true);
        DocumentBuilder docBuilder;
        try {
            docBuilder = docFactory.newDocumentBuilder();
            Document doc = docBuilder.newDocument();
            Element rootElement = doc.createElementNS("www.DATA.com/XML", "Contact");
            doc.appendChild(rootElement);
            BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
            System.out.println("Enter details of shipments:");
            String line=buf.readLine();
            String[] columns = line.split(":");
            String id = columns[0];
            String street = columns[1];
            String city = columns[2];
            String state = columns[3];
            String zipcode = columns[4];
            String country = columns[5];

            // create a book object from the data in the columns
            trial p = new trial(id, street, city,state,zipcode,country);

            // close the input stream
            buf.close();
            //append first child element to root element
            rootElement.appendChild(getShipmentDetails(doc, id,street, city,state,zipcode,country));

            // write the content into xml file
            TransformerFactory transformerFactory = TransformerFactory.newInstance();
            Transformer transformer = transformerFactory.newTransformer();
            DOMSource source = new DOMSource(doc);
            StreamResult result = new StreamResult(new File("ContactDetails.xml"));
            transformer.transform(source, result);

            // Output to console for testing
            StreamResult consoleResult = new StreamResult(System.out);
            transformer.transform(source, consoleResult);
            System.out.println("");
            System.out.println("XML file saved");
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private static Node getShipmentDetails(Document doc, String id, String street, String city, String state, String zipcode, String country  ) 
    {
        Element address = doc.createElement("address");

        //set id attribute
        address.setAttribute("addressId", id);

        //create street element
        address.appendChild(getShipmentElements(doc, address, "street", street));

        //create city element
        address.appendChild(getShipmentElements(doc, address, "city", city));

        //create state element
        address.appendChild(getShipmentElements(doc, address, "state", state));

        //create zipcode element
        address.appendChild(getShipmentElements(doc, address, "zipcode", zipcode));

        //create country element
        address.appendChild(getShipmentElements(doc, address, "country", country));

        return address;
    }

//utility method to create text node

    private static Node getShipmentElements(Document doc, Element element, String name, String value) {
        Element node = doc.createElement(name);
        node.appendChild(doc.createTextNode(value));
        return node;
    }
}
```

Expected output:

```xml
<address id="121">
  <street>xxxx</street>
  <city>xxxx</city>
  <state>xxxx</state>
  <zipcode>xxxx</zipcode>
  <country>xxxx</country>
</address>
<address id="123">
  <street>xxxx</street>
  <city>xxxx</city>
  <state>xxxx</state>
  <zipcode>xxxx</zipcode>
  <country>xxxx</country>
</address>
```

Comment: wow, that code style and formatting ...

Comment: what's wrong with calling the `readLine()` method of the buffered reader multiple times, maybe in a while loop? seriously, multiple times doing what you're already doing, isn't this obviously the use-case of a loop? Or am I missing some pitfall here?

Comment: I tried before, but doesn't works.. don't know whether i have missed  anything@aksw

Comment: hm, can you explain what "doesn't work" means? the general loop is `BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
InputStreamReader(System.in));
      String line;
      while ((line = in.readLine()) != null) {
        // do your stuff here  }`

Comment: Wouldn't a GUI make obtaining user input easier in this situation rather than using the console?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do the following to achieve what you want. I am posting only the loop part where you say you have confusion. You can ask the user to input the container items by putting a : between each item within a container and a space between individual containers.

```
BufferedReader buf = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(System.in));
        System.out.println("Enter details of shipments with *ONLY ONE* space in between multiple lines. Please separate items in one shipping container with :");
        String line = buf.readLine();

        //First separate out the space.
        String[] columnStrings = line.split(" ");

        for (String columnString : columnStrings) {
            String[] columns = columnString.split(":");
            String id = columns[0];
            String street = columns[1];
            String city = columns[2];
            String state = columns[3];
            String zipcode = columns[4];
            String country = columns[5];
            // close the input stream
            buf.close();
            //append first child element to root element
            rootElement.appendChild(getShipmentDetails(doc, id, street, city, 
state, zipcode, country));
        }
```

Also, I don't know why you were using the trial statement. I removed it and the program compiled just fine. You can loop over each line and keep adding more elements within the XML. The final XML after the above code executes is this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<Contact xmlns="www.DATA.com/XML">
<address addressId="121">
    <street>xxxx</street>
    <city>slm</city>
    <state>tn</state>
    <zipcode>636007</zipcode>
    <country>ind</country>
</address>
<address addressId="123">
    <street>yyyy</street>
    <city>chn</city>
    <state>tn</state>
    <zipcode>600009</zipcode>
    <country>ind</country>
</address>
```

Please try out this code once and see. Thank you

Instead of taking the entire input from the user at once, you can take one line per input from the user. First thing is to ask the user for the number of You can do something like

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter number of shipments");
String noOfShipments = input.nextLine();
//NumberUtils class is from apache commons
if(!NumberUtils.isNumber(noOfShipments)) {
    throw new IllegalArgumentException("The number of shipments is supposed to be an integer");
}
int shipmentNo = Integer.parseInt(noOfShipments);
for(int i=0;i<shipmentNo;i++) {
    System.out.println("Enter shipment details for shipment no "+(i+1));
    String shipmentDetail = input.nextLine();  // Read shipment details
    //Do something with this input and keep parsing until the end of the for loop
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Ashish. What would be the case if i give input as 121: 666 Ontario Street:slm:tn:636007:ind 123:359 Cherry road:chn:tn:600009:ind . Second part of input has Space, so how can split happens for multiple lines?